# CoffeeScript: Using Objects as Arguments

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

### My Code

There's a small CoffeScript code snipped:

```
Function::trigger = (prop, getter, setter) ->
      Object.defineProperty this.prototype
              get: getter,
          set: setter
```

### The JavaScript Compilation

The compiler outputs:

```
Function.prototype.trigger = function(prop, getter, setter) {
  Object.defineProperty(this.prototype({
    get: getter
  }));
  return {
    set: setter
  };
};
```

But I want the output to be:

```
Function.prototype.trigger = function(prop, getter, setter) {
  Object.defineProperty(this.prototype({
    get: getter
    set: setter
  };
};
```

### My Questions

- Why does the compiler output something that strange?
- How can I **change my code** in order to get the compiler to output what *I* want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. Also notice how you forgot the comma after this.prototype, this is making the CoffeeScript compiler think you're trying to execute the function named this.prototype with an object as an argument.

```
Function::trigger = (prop, getter, setter) ->
      Object.defineProperty this.prototype
              get: getter,
          set: setter
```

The above code should look like this. Please note that I made some changes to make it more "CoffeeScript-like" :)

```
Function::trigger = (prop, getter, setter) ->
    Object.defineProperty @::,
        get: getter
        set: setter
```

**Remember, CoffeeScript is whitespace-significant**. CoffeeScript also removes a lot of the "fluff" you see in JavaScript (commas, parens, curly braces, etc). Because of this, **formatting your code to comply with CoffeeScript standards is vital** to writing code that compiles how you expect. If you don't, the compiler will be forced to make guesses as to what you were trying to do, and it's often wrong.

The above example correctly compiles to the following JavaScript (based on coffeescript.org)...

```
Function.prototype.trigger = function(prop, getter, setter) {
  return Object.defineProperty(this.prototype, {
    get: getter,
    set: setter
  });
};
```

Please note that CoffeeScript will automatically return the last executed expression (in this case, the call to Object.defineProperty). If you want to avoid this behavior (you shouldn't, but sometimes you need to) you can just add a return statement at the end of your Function.prototype.trigger function, as such:

```
Function::trigger = (prop, getter, setter) ->
    Object.defineProperty @::,
        get: getter
        set: setter

    return
```

Which will compile to...

```
Function.prototype.trigger = function(prop, getter, setter) {
  Object.defineProperty(this.prototype, {
    get: getter,
    set: setter
  });
};
```